# Передача указателя в sizeof

Tags: c

Как правильно передать указатель в sizeof? Правильно ли я работаю в данном примере?:

```
int *arr;
arr = (int*) malloc(5 * sizeof(*arr));
printf("Выделенная память равна: %d байт\n", 5 * sizeof(*arr));
//заполним массив
....
//обнулим значения в этой памяти
memset(arr, 0, 5 * sizeof(*arr));
```

Так как arr указатель, то и нужно передавать со звездой, верно?

Comment: Результат `sizeof` имеет тип `size_t`, по каковой причине передавать его в `printf` со спецификатором формата `%d` нельзя - поведение не определено. Корректный спецификатор формата для `size_t` - `%zu`

Comment: @Ant хм, если прописать %zu в студии, то значение переменной выведено не будет.

Comment: Зависит от версии Студии. `%zu` - это С99, поддержка которого появилась в VS2013 и доделывалась в VS2015. В VS2015 `%zu` перекрасно работает, хоть в доках и не описана. Если нет поддержки для `%zu`, то тогда уж лучше `printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) (5 * sizeof *arr));`

Comment: @AnT понятно, у меня 2012 студия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(<элемет>)`  Возврашает размер памяти в байтах для элемента, которая будет выделена.

Если Мы работаем в 32-х разрядной системе, то следующие конструкции делают одинаковое действие, выделяют 20 байт в памяти.

```
void * v = malloc(20);

char * c = (char *)malloc(20);

int * i = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

int ** pi = (int **)malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));

struct s{
  char c;
  int i;
  long long int lli;
  int * pi;
  short int s;
  char s; 
}__attribute__((packed));

struct * s = (struct s *)malloc(5 * sizeof(struct s*));

struct * s = (struct s *)malloc(sizeof(struct s));
```

Но описать эти выражения можно так.

`void * v = malloc(20);`  - создадим указатель на объект любого типа и выделим 20 байт

`char * c = (char *)malloc(20);` - создадим указатель на строку и выделим строку под 20 символов.

`int * i = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));` - создадим указатель на на тип `int` и выделим память под 5 элементов `int`

`int ** pi = (int **)malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));`  - создадим уазатель на массив указателей `int` и выделим память под 5 указателей.

`struct * s = (struct s *)malloc(5 * sizeof(struct s*));` - создадим указатель на массив указателей на структуру s.

`struct * s = (struct s *)malloc(sizeof(struct s));` - создадим указатель на структуру s.

В программировании нет понятия `так принято` , есть стандарт языка который можно использовать.

Answer (score 4):

> Так как arr указатель, то и нужно передавать со звездой, верно?

По сути верно, но формулировка неверная :) Вам нужно не "передать указатель", а узнать размер элемента массива. Традиционно делается так:

```
arr = (int*) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

Но поскольку конструкция `*arr` в данном случе возвращает первый элемент массива `arr`, то при неправильных вводных мы получили правильный результат :)

> //обнулим значения в этой памяти

[man calloc](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=calloc&category=3) же!

---

Проверяем:

```
int main()
{
    int *arr;
    arr = (int*) malloc(5 * sizeof(*arr));
    printf("Allocated %zu bytes\n", 5 * sizeof(*arr));
    free(arr);
    arr = (int*) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    printf("Allocated %zu bytes\n", 5 * sizeof(int));
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Allocated 20 bytes
Allocated 20 bytes
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45622/discussion-on-answer-by-pink-tux----sizeof).

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае разницы нет, памяти будет выделено одинаково в любом случае - по 4 байта на элемент. Но если бы тип был другой, то тогда все меняется.

Да, в приведенном коде нужно передавать с звездочкой, что бы sizeof посчитал размер типа, а не размер указателя.

Comment: *В Вашем случае разницы нет, памяти будет выделено одинаково в любом случае - по 4 байта на элемент.* - не совсем так. `sizeof(int)` и `sizeof(int*)` могут ой как различаться.

Comment: @Pink Tux да, различаются. int без звезды дает 8 байт, а со звездой 4. Вот это мне и непонятно: почему так?

Comment: @Tkas, потому что размер `int` в вашей архитектуре 4 байта, а размер `int*` (то есть указателя на `int`) - 8 байт.

Comment: @Pink Tux точно, так как указатель хранит еще и свой адрес. Спасибо.

Comment: `sizeof(*arr)` - тут размер `int`а, а не указателя. `*arr` - это `arr[0]`, который int. Размер указателя был бы при передаче просто `arr`.

Comment: @Tkas: "так как указатель хранит *еще и* свой адрес" - это вы о чем? Указатель хранит адрес и только адрес. Больше ничего. Поэтому ни о каком "еще и" речи не идет. Вы, очевидно, работаете на 64-битной архитектуре, на которой адрес имеет размер 64 бита. Вот поэтому тип `int *` и имеет размер 8 байт.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> sizeof(*arr)
> ```

```
sizeof(int)
```

> ```
> memset(arr, 0, 5 * sizeof(*arr));
> ```

```
free(arr);
```

> обнулим значения в этой памяти

Это не требуется для её освобождения. Более того, если компилятор уверен, что память не используется после этого обнуления, он вправе его не выполнять. Для стирания sensitive данных следует использовать специальную функцию.

https://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/272243/ - пункт 3.
https://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/281072/

Comment: а о какой функции Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Добавил ссылки. Цитата из одной из них: _В Visual Studio, например, можно использовать RtlSecureZeroMemory. Начиная с C11 существует функция memset_s. В случае необходимости вы можете создать свою собственную безопасную функцию._

Comment: @Tkas, если обнуление нужно для работы с памятью, то имеет смысл использовать `calloc` вместо `malloc/memset`. Если для стирания данных, чтобы после освобождения памяти или по завершению программы до них не мог добраться злобный негодяй - другой вопрос.

Comment: @PinkTux вот я не очень понимаю в моем конкретном случае разницу между malloc и calloc. Они же делают одно и то же при выделении памяти.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, очень интересная информация.

Comment: @Tkas, мнение что `calloc` это почти то же самое, что `malloc+memset`, имело право на жизнь, но очень давно :) И в догонку, чтобы не плодить комменты в предыдущей ветке: а какая нужда заставляет писать на C в VS?

Comment: @Pink Tux никакая, просто под рукой была студия, gcc на домашней машине отсутствует. А почему сейчас не имеет права на жизнь? )

Comment: @Pink Tux: В упор не вижу проблемы использования С в VS. Откуда возник такой вопрос?